# How to send request body in get method retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using the retrofit library for network calls. In this, I need to pass Body in GET Method. But I am getting the error while I am passing this one. In Postman it is working while passing Body for GET Method.

```
@GET("http://192.168.0.141:3000/api/contacts/{page_num}/{limit}")
fun getAllContacts(@Path("page_num") page_num:Int,@Path("limit") limit:Int,@Body reqBody:ContactsInpRequest):Call<AllContactsDataResponse>
```

I am calling get method by passing body. But I am getting the below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.

Comment: Get method cannot have body. The parameters for Get request are appended to URL itself. For More Info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

Comment: @gprathour "while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined." The documentation you linked doesn't say that GET requests cannot have a body, it only says that the semantics for it are undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GET method does not contain body like the POST does. Here you can learn more about REST methods: https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

EDIT: I see that you said that it works in Postman so take a look at this:

***CAN GET request have a body?**

In other words, any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. ... Yes, you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning.*

Answer (score 4):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body
```

This means your @GET or @DELETE should not have @Body parameter. You can use query type url or path type url or Query Map to fulfill your need. Else you can use other method annotation.

Comment: But when i am passing body in GET Method in postman it is wokring fine.

Comment: Yes, postman updated this but you should not post body through get request instead change your method to post.

Comment: At least in my case, that isn't an option. The backend really does want a body in a GET request. The backend uses the values from the body for filtering and formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
   @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("helper-url")
fun getHelperUrl(
    @Query("api_token") apiToken: String,
    @Query("authtype") authType: String,
    @Query("channel") channel: String
): Call<ResponseHelperUrl>
```