# GET request with Query as object

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, mvvm, retrofit2

I need to make @GET request with parameters likes this:

```
@GET("some_url")
suspend fun getSomething(
@Query("simpleString") someString: String,
@Query("objectThatINeedToPass") someObject: SomeDataObjectForGetRequest
): List<BackendObject>
```

If i'll use @Body instead of @Query than Android Studio throws exception like this:
"..... @Body used with non-body request"

Please help me!

Comment: GET requests usually don't have a body. maybe Retrofit disallows it. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026072/how-to-send-request-body-in-get-method-retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests don't have a request body, you should use POST if you send a body